# How to count checked items in iTunes using Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I am trying to create a small script that takes a list of selected items and counts the number of times each selected item appears elsewhere in the library. If there are duplicates, it turns the checkmark off, if this is the only copy, it turns it on.

This works.

But what I want to do is have it check the library of checked songs only. But when I add the "enabled" bit at the end (of the third `set` line), the script times out.

```
repeat with entry in selection -- "selection" is a concept implemented in iTunes 
    set a to artist of entry
    set n to name of entry
    set x to count of (file tracks whose name contains n and artist contains a and enabled is true)
    ...
    display dialog x
end repeat
```

if I take out the `and enabled is true` it completes in double quick time as expected, and results are as expected.

with `and enabled is true` at the end of the lines something mysterious is happening. Obviously I'm checking incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick workaround:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with entry in selection -- "selection" is a concept implemented in iTunes 
        set a to artist of entry
        set n to name of entry
        set myTracks to (file tracks whose name contains n and artist contains a)
        set x to {}
        repeat with aTrack in myTracks
            if aTrack's enabled = true then set end of x to aTrack
        end repeat
        display dialog (count x)
    end repeat
end tell
```